# Recent work on Pseudo-Laplacian and Pseudo-cuspform in the spirit of Riemann Hypothesis after the work of Bombieri and Garrett

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, analytic-number-theory, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian

( This is my first MO question . I'm totally inexperienced on MO so, forgive me for my mistakes .)

Paul Garrett and Enrico Bombieri were (are?) Secretly Working on Pseudo-Laplacians and Pseudo-cuspforms ( inspired after Y. Colin de Verdi`ere 1983 paper),in spirit of Riemann hypothesis ,for several years.

In 2018 "Perspectives on Riemann hypothesis" conference they both reported ( in forms of lectures) the progress they made .([here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://aimath.org/wp-content/uploads/bristol-2018-slides/Bombieri-talk.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5P21hp3oAhW993MBHeCaBQgQFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw39ZFqYotgVlk65zeVF25-B&cshid=1584294937922) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/pseudo-cuspforms.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5P21hp3oAhW993MBHeCaBQgQFjABegQIBBAC&usg=AOvVaw0rEeSeIRPP2trdqx3KJH9v&cshid=1584294937922))

Recently (Feb 2020) they uploaded the official preprint on arxiv ([here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://arxiv.org/abs/2002.07929&ved=2ahUKEwiZ5P21hp3oAhW993MBHeCaBQgQFjAEegQIBRAL&usg=AOvVaw1rzAPMhqksj1BEdoHgd-XI&cshid=1584294937922))

There are three questions I like to ask :

> (1) Even though the official preprint is very recent but the announcement of this argument is in the mentioned conference (2 years earlier ) . So, is there anyone (other than them) working on the subject (seriously) ?. Also with eyes of other experts how promising is this approach?
>
> (2) Is this a suitable topic for Polymath project ?
>
> (3)(Main question) There is an open problem in end of Bombieri's lecture
>
> i.e. find an asymptotic formula for
>
> $$\frac{1}{4πi}\int_{(1/2)}|E_s(D)|^2\frac{ds}{λ_s^2}$$
>
> What's the status of this problem ?

Comment: Neither "was" nor "is", but "were".

Comment: Eh, I wouldn’t characterize it as secretly.

Comment: Why there's a downvote!? (Should I add a soft question tag?)